# mvc url redirection - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect, mapping

I'm going through the exercise from the book (just starting to learn MVC). I have made the following change to *RouteConfig.cs* file:

```
routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{*pathinfo}", new { 
controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });

routes.MapRoute("About", "About/{*pathinfo}", new { controller = 
"About", action = "About" });
```

The contact page works absolutely fine but the About just throws error when trying to access it via `http://localhost:49899/About`

> Error: Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.  Requested URL: /About

I cannot see any difference between those 2 lines of the code, can anybody point me to what I'm missing? This is a brand new project with all the default settings and scaffolding.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem in a new MVC project. Could you please post for whole Routing config file, and also your `About` action from your `AboutCountroller` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the default project, all kinds of wizardry happened behind the scenes for you. The default project most likely came with an auto-generated HomeController, an auto-generated Home folder to contain Views that the Home Controller will call, some Actions that correspond to those Views.

You probably do not have a Controller named About. The route that you have defined for About is saying that to get to the About page you would go through the About controller and call the About Action. Most likely you need to hit the Home Controller and then the About Action.

P.S. MVC uses naming conventions to infer where things are. You'll probably find an About view in the view folder named Home. Are you seeing a pattern here?
[Routing docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: hi. the issue was within the .net framework version itself. The original project was created in 3.5 I have recreated it in mvc 4.6 and it worked just fine. I am not too sure what was causing the issue but glad it is working now